# Будьте добры подскажите как в c# можно считанные данные из csv файла распарсить в коллекцию моделей?

Tags: c#

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO;

public class Form 
{
    public string Rank { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Country { get; set; }
    public string Rating { get; set; }
    public string Games { get; set; }
    public string BYear { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (TextFieldParser parser = new TextFieldParser(@"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Top100ChessPlayers.csv"))
        {
            List<string> list = new List<string>();
            List<Form> files = new List<Form>();
            parser.TextFieldType = FieldType.Delimited;
            parser.SetDelimiters(";");
            while (!parser.EndOfData)
            {
                //Process row
                string[] fields = parser.ReadFields();
                foreach (string field in fields)
                {
                    list.Add(field);
                }
            }
        }            
    }
}
```

Comment: А что в CSV файле? Приведите пример данных с заголовком, если он есть.

Comment: `list.Add(new Form { Rank = fields[0], Name = fields[1] }`. Цикл `foreach` убрать.

Comment: В CSV файле турнирная таблица с заголовком состоящим из тех полей что и аксессоры. Я тоже думал так прописать как вы мне подсказали

Comment: но там сотня строк и хотелось бы это как то через цикл провести

Comment: Или я неправильно понял. Получается он по столбцам записывает. Не знаю как это вывести в консоль  чтоб посмотреть

Comment: Спасибо большое, действительно сохраняет данные как надо. Еще бы очень помогло, если бы подсказали как их вывести в консоль. Например первые 5 объектов коллекции? Заранее благодарю